Camera is not working
I don't know why my camera stopped working. This is my 3rd install of Ubuntu though. By the way, I'm new to Linux
[ 2894.391056] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 17
[ 2894.672973] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 2894.814074] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=212b, bcdDevice=56.14
[ 2894.814096] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2894.814103] usb 1-3: Product: Integrated Camera
[ 2894.814110] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: SunplusIT Inc
[ 2894.848986] usb 1-3: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (5986:212b)
[ 2894.849353] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 2 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.849727] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 3 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.850110] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 6 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.850477] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 7 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.850851] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 8 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.851228] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 9 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.851601] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.851986] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 1 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.852353] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 5 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.852726] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.853099] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.853477] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 3 on unit 1: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.853851] usb 1-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -71 (exp. 1).
[ 2894.854602] usb 1-3: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[ 2894.854981] uvcvideo 1-3:1.1: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -71 (exp. 26).
[ 2894.854996] uvcvideo 1-3:1.1: Failed to initialize the device (-71).
[ 2894.855594] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 18

